# CSS flexgrid styling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am just trying to get the grid row to look the way I want and I have a large CSS and can't seem to get the column with three rows of the text right.  There's the photo to indicate where the obvious entry should read from.

```css
/* reset */
html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,
code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,dl,dt,dd,ol,nav ul,nav li,
fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,embed,
figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,output,ruby,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video
{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font-size:100%;font:inherit;vertical-align:baseline;}
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {display: block;}
ol,ul{list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;}
blockquote,q{quotes:none;}
blockquote:before,blockquote:after,q:before,q:after{content:'';content:none;}
table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
/* start editing from here */
a{text-decoration:none;}
.txt-rt{text-align:right;}/* text align right */
.txt-lt{text-align:left;}/* text align left */
.txt-center{text-align:center;}/* text align center */
.float-rt{float:right;}/* float right */
.float-lt{float:left;}/* float left */
.clear{clear:both;}/* clear float */
.pos-relative{position:relative;}/* Position Relative */
.pos-absolute{position:absolute;}/* Position Absolute */
.vertical-base{ vertical-align:baseline;}/* vertical align baseline */
.vertical-top{  vertical-align:top;}/* vertical align top */
.underline{ padding-bottom:5px; border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; margin:0 0 20px 0;}/* Add 5px bottom padding and a underline */
nav.vertical ul li{ display:block;}/* vertical menu */
nav.horizontal ul li{display: inline-block;}/* horizontal menu */
img{max-width:100%;}
/*end reset*/
body {
    background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/sCfeeeY.png) ;
    background-position: top 1em right 1em, bottom 1em left 1em;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.row {
    flex: 2 auto;
    grid-column: 1 30em;
    display: flex;
    margin: auto;
}
.active {
    margin: 1em;
}
.fullwebpage .section {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: .4rem;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    /* grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(40em, ifr));  */
    grid-column: 1;
    flex: 0 1 28em;
}
.box {
    display: flex;
    align-items:center;
    grid-column: 4;
    flex: 3 auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top:1.5em;
    padding-left: 2em;
}
.sectionheader {
    display: flex;
    flex: 8 auto;
    grid-row: auto 1;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 1em;
    /* padding-left: 3em; */
    margin-right: 3em;
}
.sectionfirst {
     margin-left: 5em;
    /*margin-right:2em;
    height:39em; */
    padding-top: 1em;
}
.head_bg {
    padding-top:1.5em;
    padding-left: 2em;
}
.section_bg .head_bg a:active {
    color: black;
}
.header {
    padding-left: 2em;
    padding-right:3em;
}
.logo {
    margin-left: 3em;
    margin-right: 2em;
}
.links {
    padding-bottom:1em;
}
.links li a {
    color: white;
}
.footer a:active {
    color: white;
}
 .promo_slogan_mid {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 40px;
    align-items: start;
    text-align: start;
}
.promo_slogan_mid p {
    font-size: 1vw;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.promo_slogan {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 3vw;
    align-items: center;
    word-wrap: break-word;
} 
.promo_slogan p {
    font-size: 1vw;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.nav_menu {
    float: left;
    /* margin-left: 0em;*/
    margin-right: 1.5em; 
    justify-content: space-around;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: flex;
    z-index: 1;
}
.nav_menu a {
    margin: .3em 1.3em;
} 
.updateinput#gsbutton {
    float: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    /* display: inline-block; */
    z-index: 1; 
}

.gsbutton:hover .gsbutton:active {
    border: none;
    outline: none; 
}
.wrap {
    display: inline-flex;
    width:100%;
    margin-top:1em;
}
.wrap a {
    display: flex;
    flex: 3 auto;
    flex-flow: row;
    grid-row: 1;
    float: start;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}
.footerbanner {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.container1 {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}
.col-xs {
    width:20%;
}
.sectionsecond {
    padding-top: 2em;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 3;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 1em;
    /* display: flex;
    flex: 3 auto;
    grid-row: auto 1;
    width: 100%; */
    margin: 1em;
    height:39em;
    margin-right: 3em;
}
.mycolumn_header .row_header {
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    display: block;
    text-align: center; 
}
.foot-row h1 {
    display: flex;
    /* height: 8em; */
    padding-top: 2.1em; 
    padding-bottom: 0em;
    margin: 1em 2em;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:1;
}
.updateinput#email_validate {
    text-align: end; 
    padding-top: 2.1em; 
    margin: 1em 2em;
} 
.updateinput {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 0em;
}   
.topfooterbanner div {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;    
    height: 12em;
}
.modal-content {
    border-radius: 1rem
}
.modal-content:hover {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black
}
.btn:hover a:active {
    border: none;
}
.btn {
    text-decoration: none;
}   
.fa {
    color: #2b84be;
    font-size: 90px;
    padding: 30px 0px
}
.form {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgb(10, 153, 209), rgb(5, 76, 122));
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.b1 {
    background-color: #2b84be;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px #337095;
    font-size: 17px
}
.r3 {
    color: #c1c1c1;
    font-weight: 500
}
.topfooterbanner {
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%;
}
.row_header h1 {
    /* vertical-align: bottom; */
    font-size: 3em;
    font-weight:bold;
    /* padding-bottom: 0; */
}
.foot-row h1 {
    /* vertical-align: bottom; */
    font-size: 3em;
    font-weight:bold;
    /* padding-bottom: 0; */
}
.foot-row {
    /* padding-top: 2.6em; */
    text-align: end;
    background-color:  #F97419;
    display: flex;
}
.foot-row::before {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
.statementnews {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-left: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: width 2s, height 2s, background-color 2s, transform 2s;
}
.statementnews p {
  text-align: wrap;
  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-right: 1em;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
.statementnews:hover {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
.col {
  min-width:15vw;
  min-height: 60vh;
}
.mycolumn2 {
    display: flex;
    flex: 4 auto;
    grid-row: 1 2;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 4em;
    margin: 1em;
}
.sectionthird#gsbutton_3 {
    align-items: center;
}
.sectionthird {
    padding-top: 8em;
    display: flex;
    /* grid-row: auto 3; */
}

.col-md-6#sidebar1 {
    width:60%;
    padding-top: 0em;
    padding-left: 0em;
    padding-right: 0em;
    align-items: center;
}    
.middle_id_img {
    padding-left:1em;
}
.col-md-4 {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 40px;
    align-items: start;
    text-align: start;
    /* font-size: 1vw; */
    /* font-weight: normal; */
}
.col-md-6 {
    height: 8em;
    width: 45%;
    display: flex;
    /* justify-content: space-between; */
    margin-left: 2em;
    /* padding-left: 5em; */
    padding-top: 2em;
}
.table-row {
    padding-top: 2em;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center; 
}
.table-row#content {
    height: 14em;
}
.mycolumn_header {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 45px; 
}
.sectionthird {
    padding-top: 2em;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 3;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
.mycolumn#userresponse {
    font-size: 8em; 
    font-weight: bold;  
}
.mycolumn#content_gsbutton {
    font-size: .4em;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 0;
} 
.mycolumn {
    height: 8em;
    align-items:center;
    text-align: start;
    display: table-cell;
    margin-left: 2em;
    padding-left: 1em;
    padding-top: 2em; 
}
#sidebar {
    height: 9em;
    box-shadow: -.4em 1em #888888;
    width:30%;
}  
#align_bottom {
    padding-top: 10em;
    padding-left: 40em;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 1vh;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.footer_column ul {
    padding-top: 1em;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;  
}
.gsbutton_footer {
    position: center;
}
.footer_column {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.7vh;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-left: 19em; 
    margin: 0em 1em; 
}
.sectiontopfooter {
    margin-top: 15em;
}
.sectionfooter {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    background-color: black;
}
.sectionfooter li {
    padding-top: 1em;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}   
.wrap-row#middle_id_img {
    width: 20%;
}
.wrap-row {
    padding-top: 2em;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center; 
}
.wrap-row#sidebar_col {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 3;
    padding-top: 8em;
} 
.wrap-row#box-md-3 {
    padding-top: 8em;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<section class="sectionsecond">
            <div class="wrap-row">
                <div class="box" id="box-md-3">
                    <div class="col-md-6 " id="table-element1">
                        <div class="promo_slogan_mid" id="sidebar_col">
                            <h1> What’s different about Manage?</h1>
                            <br>
                            <p>Manage provides all the functionality your team needs, without the complexity. Our software is tailor-made for modern digital product teams.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs" id="middle_id_img">
                        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/99FIu0U.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-4 promo_slogan" id="feedback_slogan">
                        <h2>Track company-wide progress</h2>
                          <p class="text_slogan">See how your day-to-day tasks fit into the wider vision. Go from 
                          tracking progress at the milestone level all the way done to the 
                          smallest of details. Never lose sight of the bigger picture again.</p>
                          <br>
                        <h2>Advanced built-in reports</h2>
                        <p class="text_slogan">Set internal delivery estimates and track progress toward company 
                          goals. Our customizable dashboard helps you build out the reports 
                          you need to keep key stakeholders informed.</p>
                          <br>
                        <h2> Everything you need in one place</h2>
                         <p class="text_slogan"> Stop jumping from one service to another to communicate, store files, 
                          track tasks and share documents. Manage offers an all-in-one team 
                          productivity solution.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

I'd really like to have the transition animation from CSS slide the row `onload()` but I can't seem to get that

Comment: are you trying to have a carousel display on the right, contect blocks 1, 2, and 3 transitioning?

Comment: @RonnieRoyston I'd like the page sections to fly onto the page with transition slide script that is there but this is just plain text on the page to the right of the middle image as three rows of text. There is a placement to see bulleted.